# How to dynamically adjust a vertical side bar to automatically adjust between the header and bottom of browser

Tags: html, css

The below code is auto justifying the menu items vertically to the browser window, but it doesn't take the header into consideration. How can I vertically justify the side bar between the header and the bottom of the browser. Currently the bottom items are extending below the bottom of the browser.

HTML:

```
<h1>
Header
</h1>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar{
  background-color: orange;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.sidebar ul{
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  margin:0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: is header height known?

Comment: should the menu be styled with `position:fixed` to be always visible at fix position if the page contain vertical scrollbar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using.

HTML:

```
<h1>
Header
</h1>
  <section>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <main>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
    <p>main content</p>
  </main>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
main {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
}
body, .sidebar, .sidebar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sidebar ul {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.sidebar{
  background-color: orange;
}
.sidebar ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  margin:0px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap header and sidebar in another flexbox.
[This is the example](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/15kcu4vw/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex">
    <h1>
    Header
    </h1>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.sidebar{
  flex:1;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0px;
}

.sidebar ul{
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  margin:0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: You should put your HTML and CSS in the `<>` editor in the SO answer so we have a live demo that doesn't link to a 3rd party site like jsfiddle.

Comment: Probably you are right, it is a my personal preference, especially if there are external resource or some framework. I will try to use the internal engine next time :)